# Session variable leaking into global namespace

Tags: php, session, global, memory-leaks

index.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['a']='test';
echo $a;
die();
```

When I run the above, the first time I get a blank screen with no error. After page refresh it outputs the word `test`

It does not do this on my development server, only on production (shared on Hostgator).

Is this a server fault?

Comment: register_globals defines it. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register_globals` is unfortunately turned on with your Hostgator hosting.  You'll need to turn it off in your php.ini, if they give you access to it.

Comment: You should look for a better host.  register_globals has been deprecated since PHP 5, and I believe outright removed since 5.3.  It hasn't been turned on by default for 5+ years.  That it's on with your host should be considered a warning sign.

Comment: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/register-globals-and-other-php-settings

Comment: To follow up, the instructions in the link I gave above above did not work for me. Although it succeeds in turning off register_globals it breaks other things. However, they will give you the full php.ini file and set it up with register_globals off if you request it. Seems to work now.